# Unable to install Talon library in python using pip install

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Getting this error: `numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: no lapack/blas resources found`

Similar output is seen from both pip and setup.py installation:

```
Note: if you need reliable uninstall behavior, then install
with pip instead of using `setup.py install`:

  - `pip install .`       (from a git repo or downloaded source
                           release)
  - `pip install scipy`   (last SciPy release on PyPI)


lapack_opt_info:
lapack_mkl_info:
  libraries mkl_rt not found in ['C:\\Users\\seth\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\seth\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

openblas_lapack_info:
  libraries openblas not found in ['C:\\Users\\seth\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\seth\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_3_10_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
C:\Users\seth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1051: UserWarning: Specified path C:\projects\numpy-wheels\windows-wheel-builder\atlas-builds\atlas-3.11.38-sse2-64\lib is invalid.
  pre_dirs = system_info.get_paths(self, section, key)
<enter code hereclass 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_3_10_info:
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_info:
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

C:\Users\seth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:572: UserWarning:
    Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
    the ATLAS environment variable.
  self.calc_info()
lapack_info:
  libraries lapack not found in ['C:\\Users\\seth\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\seth\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

C:\Users\seth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:572: UserWarning:
    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
    the LAPACK environment variable.
  self.calc_info()
lapack_src_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE

C:\Users\seth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:572: UserWarning:
    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
    the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
  self.calc_info()
  NOT AVAILABLE

Running from scipy source directory.
non-existing path in 'scipy\\integrate': 'quadpack.h'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\seth\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-g7y49dg2\scipy\setup.py", line 416, in <module>
    setup_package()
  File "C:\Users\seth\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-g7y49dg2\scipy\setup.py", line 412, in setup_package
    setup(**metadata)
  File "C:\Users\seth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 135, in setup
    config = configuration()
  File "C:\Users\seth\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-g7y49dg2\scipy\setup.py", line 336, in configuration
    config.add_subpackage('scipy')
  File "C:\Users\seth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1029, in add_subpackage
    caller_level = 2)
  File "C:\Users\seth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 998, in get_subpackage
    caller_level = caller_level + 1)
  File "C:\Users\seth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 935, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
    config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
  File "scipy\setup.py", line 15, in configuration
    config.add_subpackage('linalg')
  File "C:\Users\seth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1029, in add_subpackage
    caller_level = 2)
  File "C:\Users\seth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 998, in get_subpackage
    caller_level = caller_level + 1)
  File "C:\Users\seth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 935, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
    config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
  File "scipy\linalg\setup.py", line 20, in configuration
    raise NotFoundError('no lapack/blas resources found')
numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: no lapack/blas resources found
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: maybe this https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/5995

Comment: Getting all the tools necessary to install this without just using a pre-packaged distribution on windows is going to be an exercise in frustration. just go install the anaconda distribution or winpython.